# Tried to ask the question "Are atheists considered gentile or something else?" but was not accepted by the system!

Tags: discussion, policy, asking-questions

Hello,

I tried asking the question "Are atheists considered gentile or something else?" in the main forum but was not accepted by the system!

What rule does that question violate?

Edit Below:

I tried it again and this is the message I got :

> Oops! Your question couldn't be
>   submitted because:  •Sorry, we can't
>   accept this question.

I tagged it with gentile-non-jews tag

Regards

Comment: Did you get an error message and/or a screenshot you could post?

Comment: Hi @Rebecca, I edited my question. tx

Comment: the question body will also be necessary to diagnose this.

Comment: Did you make sure to include a question body?

Comment: Hi @Isaac, yes the body was the same as the question.

Comment: The Stack Exchange software knows that you're not a Jew and forbade you from asking any questions! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have metrics that doing an analysis of posts for quality.  It is possible you got tripped up by this.  A few metrics we look at that you can check are:

- Overlap between the title and the body of the question.  The body of your question should expand on the title, so there shouldn't be a lot of overlap.
- The length of the post body.  A question doesn't need to be a novel, but it should be a couple sentences at least.
- Grammar and spelling.  Use sentences.  Don't use txt-speak.

Comment: If thats the case, is it possible for the error message to include details of how to fix it?

Comment: @AviD I think they avoid giving too much information away to avoid people cheating the system.